# ADF Lookup/Join Returning Longest String

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am running into an odd issue where ADF is only returning matches for the longest string in a column when joining or looking up.

Example: Left table has multiple values of "len" and "length". Right table has ID 1 for "len" and 2" for "length". However, no matter how I set up the join or lookup data flow activity, it will only return ID 2 for "length" and NULL for ID 1 for "len".

If all values are of the same string length (e.g. "len","pen","abc", etc.) it will find a match for all records.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you got the First Row Only option set?  It’s the default so probably worth ruling out first.

Comment: I have it matching on Any Row. Two of my flows are behaving like this and I have one flow behaving as expected. Everything is set up exactly the same, which is what I do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not sure if this qualifies as "user error", but I used dummy files to test whether it was ADF causing the issue or my data and I was able to successfully lookup all data with the dummy files.

This prompted me to troubleshoot why ADF wouldn't match against my SQL tables.

I ended up **modifying** the source lookup table by **trimming** the string column (even though the table does not have spaces or tabs in the column) and ADF found all matches.

A bit underwhelming, but putting this here in case anyone else runs across the same issue.